# Conditional OnClick popup will not appear as top window - Dependent on DB & WizardControl textbox value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, messagebox, showdialog

Windows 7, C# Web Application, VS 2012, .NET 3.5, testing primarily on Google Chrome.

I have a wizard control with several steps. The first step has a form that the user fills out and when they click "Save & Continue >>"(StartNavigationTemplate's btnNext), I need to check what's in the textbox txtIDno(if anything is listed. This textbox may be left empty for new properties being added for the first time), run this value through the database to ensure that the number matches up with a property we have listed. If the value is valid, the user should be directed to the next wizard step. If the value is not valid, there should be a modal pop-up window informing the user that the ID No is incorrect, and they should NOT be redirected to the next step.

Thinking this would be an easy task, I first tried using MessageBox.Show() in the button's click event, wzDataEntry_ActiveStepChanged. *The popup message does appear when it should*, however unless I am stepping through the code in debug mode, the *popup always appears BEHIND the internet window* (This was tested on Chrome, IE, & Mozilla Firefox). This *allows the user to continue to edit the form, although it properly does not redirect to the next step. The problem is that the popup doesn't populate a new item on the taskbar either, so it will surely go unnoticed and the user may wonder why they cannot navigate to the next step of the wizard.*

Wizard control basics from .aspx:

```
<div id="wizardContainer" class="wizard-container">
                    <asp:Wizard DisplaySideBar="true" 
                        OnSideBarButtonClick="wzDataEntry_SideBarClick"
                        OnPreviousButtonClick="wzDataEntry_ActiveStepChanged"
                        OnNextButtonClick="wzDataEntry_ActiveStepChanged" 
                        OnFinishButtonClick="wzDataEntry_FinishButtonClick" ID="wzDataEntry" runat="server" Width="100%" ActiveStepIndex="1">
                        <SideBarStyle CssClass="wizard-sidebar" />
                        <SideBarTemplate>
                            <div class="wizard-sidebar-container">
                                <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="SideBarList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    //Stuff
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <SeparatorTemplate>
                                    //Stuff
                                    </SeparatorTemplate>
                                </asp:DataList>
                            </div>
                        </SideBarTemplate>
                        <StartNavigationTemplate>
                            <div class="wizard-navigation">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text=" Save & Continue >> " CssClass="action-button ds-save-changes"
                                    CommandName="MoveNext" />
                            </div>
                        </StartNavigationTemplate>

                        <StepNavigationTemplate>
                        //stuff
                        </StepNavigationTemplate>

                        <FinishNavigationTemplate>
                        //stuff
                        </FinishNavigationTemplate>

                        <WizardSteps>
                            <asp:WizardStep ID="stepPropertyInfo" Title="Property" AllowReturn="true" StepType="Auto" runat="server">
                                 <div class="clear clearfix top-navigation-buffer"></div>
                                <input type="hidden" id="property-information-step" class="property-information-step" />
                                <div id="Div2" class="data">
                                    <table id="tblPropertyInformationContainer">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div id="Div3">
                                                    <table id="tblPropertyInformation" class="data-entry-table">
                                                          <tr>
                                                            <td class="label">
                                                                ID#
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIDNo" runat="server" CssClass="id-number" MaxLength="10" Width="80" TabIndex="22" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>                                 
                                                  </div>
                                             </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                            </asp:WizardStep>
                           <asp:WizardStep ID="stepOwnerInformation" Title="Seller" AllowReturn="true" StepType="Auto" runat="server">     
                            //Stuff here                      
                            </asp:WizardStep>
                        </WizardSteps>
                    </asp:Wizard>
                </div>
```

Button click from .aspx.cs:

```
    public void wzDataEntry_ActiveStepChanged(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
            {
                int activestep = e.CurrentStepIndex;

                if (activestep == (int)DealInputSteps.PropertyInformation && txtIDno.Text != "" && validateID(txtIDno.Text) == false){
                string message = String.Concat("There was an error saving form because ", txtIDno.Text, " is not a valid ID number. Please confirm the ID number and try again.");

                    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(message); -> I tried this first. This populates item on taskbar but the popup is still hidden behind browser. 
                    //Then I found on SO that TopMost=true should bring this window to the forefront...but it doesn't.
                   //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(new System.Windows.Forms.Form { TopLevel = true }, message); -> Same effect as TopMost
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(new System.Windows.Forms.Form { TopMost = true }, message); //Popup appears behind browser, no item on Windows taskbar, user can still edit form, wizard (properly) does not move on to next step
                    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(message, title, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Warning, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, (System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions)0X40000); -> Throws exception

                    e.Cancel = true;                    
                }
                else
                {
                    UpdateDealStep();
                }
            }

    //I've confirmed that this function is working properly and is not root cause
    protected bool validateID(string IDno)
            {
                string result = "";
                result = //DB is queried here 
                if (result == ""){      
                    return false; 
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
```

***How can I ensure this popup will appear on top of the browser???*** It would be preferable if this would not allow input while this popup was open, as well.

I then tried using ShowDialog() instead of MessageBox. I've tried adding attributes to get the popup to appear centered with all controls visible, but I have not been successful. *This window also appears BEHIND the browser and allows the user to continue editing the form, although not allowing them to navigate to the next step. There is an item on the windows taskbar which may be an indication to the user, however the controls are squished in the top left-hand corner and are not readable.*

```
public void wzDataEntry_ActiveStepChanged(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            int activestep = e.CurrentStepIndex;

            if (activestep == (int)DealInputSteps.PropertyInformation && txtIDno.Text != "" && validateID(txtIDno.Text) == false){
            string message = String.Concat("There was an error saving form because ", txtMlsNumber.Text, " is not a valid ID number. Please confirm the ID number and try again.");
            string title = "Invalid ID number.";
            System.Windows.Forms.Form popup = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
            popup.Text = title;
            popup.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            popup.Controls.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Label() { Text = message, AutoSize = true, TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter });
            popup.Controls.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Button() { Text = "OK", DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK, TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomRight });
            popup.ShowDialog();    
                e.Cancel = true;                    
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateDealStep();
            }
        }
```

ShowDialog() Output:

[image]

I then thought that I might use javascript's return confirm(); method on a onclientclick() but have struggled with the accessing the txtIDno control because it is in a wizard and had trouble with formulating a conditional statement that would run my server-side function to check the database. PageMethods will not work because my validateID() function cannot be static. I am sure that I am likely missing a bigger picture concept in regards to client vs server-side conditional functions, but I can post all my failed attempts at this if no one can offer a solution to my MessageBox() &/or ShowDialog() issues.

Any insight as to what I am doing wrong or what the best practice might be here???? I've spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to figure out such a small piece of functionality and am at a loss.

***EDIT:***

*Partial Solutions:*

I have found some workarounds from my aspx.cs, however there are some undesired consequential effects.

1. This is the best one so far, as it makes the popup appear as top window. While the popup is present and before the page fully loads, however, two other buttons on my page disappear. They reappear as soon as the user clicks OK to close the popup, but it'd be preferred if this did not occur. It appears this is only occurring to the buttons that have a server-side variable (<%= >) in them. **Is there a way to make the page seamlessly postback at once when the dialog box is closed?**

> System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(message, title,
>   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,
>   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Warning,
>   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
>   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);

2. This method's behavior causes its execution right before the Page_Load, which seems to be occurring before the Master Page loads... While the popup is present, there is no background image or header on my page. Similarly to solution 1 above, everything does load properly AFTER the user clicks OK to close the popup. **Is there a way to call this javascript function either before the page starts to postback or after the whole page has loaded?**

> Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "test",
>   "alert('" + message + "')", true);

3. This is not a pretty solution, but it works more seamlessly than the two above. The problem here is that when the page posts back, the CSS for my table is gone. **How can I make my page retain its CSS after a JS function postback?**

   > string alert = "< script language='javascript' >";
   >
   > alert += "alert('" + message + "');";
   >
   > alert += "< /script >";
   >
   > Response.Write(alert);